# Migrate web site from Google Drive to Google Sites

Tags: google-classic-sites

I have a web site that is totally functional on Google Drive.  Unfortunately, the company for which I work is starting to block Google Drive for security reasons.  Is there a way I could move my site from Google Drive to Google Sites.  Or would I just have to create the web site from scratch.

I can't even see how to create the directory structure, let alone get html pages into that structure.

Comment: Add more details about your web site, like the number of webpages and the kind of resources they require.

Answer (score 1):

In Google sites it's not possible to upload your own HTML or view any of the FTP tree the only way to edit/create pages is through the built in editor . But there are **many** alternatives out there. I'd recommend [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/) for a free web host. I use it for my file servers and have used it for forum sites in the past. But there are tons of services out there that can do exactly what you need to do. Just not under the Google name.

The reason Google disallows such free editing is because they want to avoid any kind of phishing sites and such out of their domain.